# Selected Menu tab color hilited

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I was wondering how I would go about changing the background color of the selected tab (not the contents of the tab, the tab heading itself, when I hover over it it turns grey but then goes back to normal once I click the tab, I want it to stay grey). I was also wondering how to change the font and font color of the tab heading once selected.

Please let me know if you need any other information, I'm not really sure how much more specific I can get without taking screenshots but I will if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `css` class for selected tab header. For example, if you have html like this,

```
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a class="menuLink active" href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li> <a class="menuLink" href="#">Page1</a></li>
    <li><a class="menuLink" href="#">Page2</a></li>
    <li><a class="menuLink" href="#">Page3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

then using jQuery,

```
$('.menuLink').click(function(){
  $('a').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/PYW35/
P.S.: this question should be tagged for `jQuery`, `css`.